# Nested RecyclerView; inner child steals focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

I have one RecyclerView as the "main" stream of things. One of the things could be a RecyclerView with 2x2 grid of items.

When I launch the activity, create the fragment, create the RecyclerView, etc. in TalkBack mode,for odd reason the child of the inner RecyclerView gets the focus (its content gets read instead of the activity's title like normal -- as in other places that do not have this nested RecyclerView structure).

I must be missing something obvious.

I've tried calling `setFocusable(false)` on that child (confirmed using Hierarchy Viewer that focusable=false) yet TalkBack still focuses on it for no obvious reason. My code doesn't explicitly request for focus.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try using mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: On the outer `RecyclerView` or the inner `RecyclerView`? I tried it just now on the inner `RecyclerView` -- issue persists. Then tried on both inner and outer -- issue persists. On just the outer -- issue persists :( Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Try `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on its parent or parent of the parent it worked for me on a similar issue

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, even though I put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` (or even programmatically call `#setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` on the inner RecyclerView, that inner RecyclerView's child still stole focus.

In case it might be relevant, what was that similar issue you faced?

Comment: A `RecycleView` nested in `FrameLayout` nested in `ConstraintLayout` was stealing focus on Pager switch so `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the `ConstraintLayout` stopped the stealing

Comment: I see. In that case, was the `RecyclerView` the one stealing the focus or was it the `RecyclerView`'s child?

It was worth the try though. Thanks!

Comment: @darolandi I think it was a child because it was scrolling untouched

Comment: any idea about the latest working solution?